# Adding an array to a JSON object with VBA-JSON JsonConverter

Tags: excel, vba

I'm learning how to use the JsonConverter.bas module from GitHub (https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON).
Currently what puzzles me is how to add an array of objects to a JSON object.

My desired outcome would look like this:
json = { xmpls: [ {en: "Hi", es: "Hola"}, {en: "Bye", es: "Adios"} ] }

This is my code:

```
Sub GenerateJSON()

   Dim json As String
   Dim jsonObj As Object
   Dim xmplsArr As Collection
   Dim xmpl As Object

   Set jsonObj = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

   Set xmplsArr = New Collection


   Set xmpl = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   xmpl("en") = "Hi"
   xmpl("es") = "Hola"
   xmplsArr.Add xmpl

   Set xmpl = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   xmpl("en") = "Bye"
   xmpl("ru") = "Adios"
   xmplsArr.Add xmpl

   jsonObj("xmpls") = xmplsArr


   json = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(jsonObj)

   Range("E2").Value = json
End Sub
```

The above throws this error that goes like "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment."

How do I go about achieving my goal here?

Comment: If you're getting an error, it's useful to mention which exact line the error is occurring on.

Comment: It occurs on jsonObj("xmpls") = xmplsArr

Comment: `Set jsonObj("xmpls") = xmplsArr` or `jsonObj.Add, "xmpls", xmplArr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from comments, and adding a function to create each translation:

```vb
Sub GenerateJSON()
    Dim jsonObj As Object
    Dim xmplsArr As Collection
    
    Set jsonObj = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set xmplsArr = New Collection
    
    xmplsArr.Add Translation("en", "Hi", "es", "Hola")
    xmplsArr.Add Translation("en", "Bye", "ru", "Adios")
    
    jsonObj.Add "xmpls", xmplsArr
    
    Range("E2").Value = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(jsonObj)
End Sub

Function Translation(fromLang, orig, toLang, transl)
    Set Translation = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With Translation
        .Add fromLang, orig
        .Add toLang, transl
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: jsonObj.Add "xmpls", xmplsArr - this did the trick, thank you!!